# inserting string to clob using ibatis in db2

Tags: java, clob

i have a bean with attribute of datatype java.sql.Clob. How do i set the value of the clob object in the bean? the value is a string which is from a jsp form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution myself.
Instead of having the attribute as java.sql.Clob i changed the data type to java.lang.String data type and then changed the parameter mapping in the ibatis.xml to #clobValue:CLOB# which in turn converted the String to CLOB.

Comment: can u please look at question and help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303931/retreieve-clob-data-using-ibatis-2-3