# Retreieve CLOB data using Ibatis 2.3

Tags: java, oracle, ibatis

I am trying to retrieve a clob data from the oracle database as shown in **reports.xml**.i am using oracle jdbc driver version "**Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.0.2.0.0**" . The following are the errors i receive ,kindly let me know ,how to resolve this.

```
2011-08-31 13:03:40,790 WARN  [org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExceptionHandler] (http-10.12.230.222-8080-1) Unhandled exception
com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in sa/mobily/telecop/dao/config/GenericReportQuery.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the runReportQuery-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the parameter mapping for the 'QUERY' property.  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Data size bigger than max size for this type: 6411
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(MappedStatement.java:201)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForList(MappedStatement.java:139)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:567)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:541)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:118)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryForList(SqlMapClientImpl.java:94)
```

**reports.xml**

```
<select id="getReportQuery"  parameterClass="java.util.HashMap" resultMap="queryStringData" >
        select REPORT_QUERY 
         from frd_rep_fw_reports where report_id=#REP_ID# AND report_type='P' 
</select> 
<resultMap id="queryStringData" class="java.util.HashMap">
  <result column="REPORT_QUERY" property="QRY_BODY" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="CLOB"  typeHandler="com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.type.ClobTypeHandlerCallback" />
</resultMap>
```

**sqlmapconfig.xml**

```
<dataSource type="JNDI">
        <property name="DataSource" value="${connection.datasource}"/>
        <property name="Driver.SetBigStringTryClob" value="true"/>
    </dataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the latest ojdbc14.jar and i should work. Also let me know how the table frd_rep_fw_reports is defined

Comment: we have database column type as CLOB and at java side we are retrieving the value in String but conversion is failing for CLOB column. All other columns values are retrieved in java object but the COLB column's value in String is coming as null. Will ojdbc14.jar help to resolve the problem. Is there any role of conversion in new ojdbc14.jar ?